# Python - all the print and stdout how can i get from terminal so that i can make a log?

Tags: python, linux, bash

Why it does not give output while doing from bash `>>`, so that it can be saved to a file.

```
$ cat > /var/tmp/runme.sh << \EOF
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
python /var/tmp/t.py >> /var/tmp/log.log &
sleep 3
ps aux | grep "t.py" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9;

EOF


$ cat > /var/tmp/t.py << \EOF
import sys
print "[RAN]: OK"
sys.stdout.write("[RAN]: OK")
sys.stdout.flush()
EOF

$ chmod +x /var/tmp/runme.sh ; /var/tmp/runme.sh & 

$ cat /var/tmp/log.log

$ tail -f /var/tmp/log.log
```

^
 Showing nothing.

How can i get the outputs to log.log using Bash and Python combination?

Comment: Why don't you use the `logging` module to perform logging tasks?

Comment: @Bakuriu: i have random apps. `java | c | tee /var/tmp/log.log | xargs vala | python`

Comment: All has to get the same root outputs inside and then parse it and log them to log.log file for some debugging..

Answer (score 0):

you could have python do:

```
var = "hello world"
f = open('log.log', 'r+')
print(var)
f.write(var)
```

Comment: But the idea is to have: `java -cp Other.jar Main.Boot | tee -a /var/tmp/log.log; python py.py | tee -a /var/tmp/log.log;` not from the python doing log.log. Same log.log file shared by java, python, c etc etc

Comment: the information in your question does not refer to java in any kind. Please update your question so OP may update the answer. (End of Review).

Answer (score 0):

Within var/tmp/t.py, do something similar to the following:

```
var = "[RAN]: OK"
f = open("log.log", "a+")
f.write(var)
print var
f.close()
```

Opening "log.log" with the "a+" argument will allow you to append the output of t.py to the file so that you can keep track of multiple runs of t.py. If you just want the output for the most recent run you could just use "w+" which will create a new file if one does not exist and rewrite the file if it does.

You could also put a time stamp on each log using datetime like so:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
var = "Date: " + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") + "\n" +  "[RAN]: OK"
f = open("log.log", "a+")
f.write(var)
print var
f.close()
```

I don't know if this script is something you will run periodically in which knowing the date the log was created would be useful or whether it is a one and done script but I thought you may find date logging useful.

Comment: But the idea is to have: `java -cp Other.jar Main.Boot | tee -a /var/tmp/log.log; python py.py | tee -a /var/tmp/log.log;` not from the python doing log.log. Same log.log file shared by java, python, c etc etc

Comment: So I typed your script above verbatim into the command line and I ended up with a file log.log with the correct output written to the file. In this example are you just looking for "[RAN]: OK" to be printed to log.log or is there something I am missing?